# Showing change of lot division/ownership over time?

Tags: arcgis-pro, time, spatio-temporal-data

I am new to GIS programs and using ArcGIS Pro.

I am mapping a neighborhood and looking at creating a detailed database of the ownership history. Currently I have the lots configured to have an attribute field for each individual time the lot ownership legally changed, called an Instrument.

[image: My setup]

This is pretty basic and an ugly solution as it requires me to have 16 fields for lots that have much lower ownership changes. I've been looking into temporal options but it seems to be just for changing the Attributes. I am looking for a solution that allows the polygons in the map to change according to the time slider resulting in something like this in map form:

[image]

Comment: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/time/about-visualizing-temporal-data.htm

Comment: It seems like this

"Features that change in shape or location over time have to be stored as separate features. For example, for hurricane tracks that are being visualized over time, the point feature representing the location of a hurricane at a particular time has to be stored as a separate feature." from https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/time/how-time-is-supported-in-spatial-data.htm is what I want...

Comment: Yes, you'll need a separate polygon feature for each Instrument, each with a start and end time value.

Comment: related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115374/how-to-automate-exporting-map-for-many-fields-in-the-same-layer/115581#115581

Comment: Ahhh I think I understand now, thanks so much.

How would you keep all the different features organized since there would be lots drawn on top of each other? Just have a ton of layers?

Comment: once you time-enable your layer, only features that 'exist' at the current time will be displayed. So as long as none of your Instruments have overlapping start and end times, only one will be displayed at a time.

Comment: In your examples, from 1907-1963 you would only see the third feature, then for all of 1964 you would see the second and third, then from 1965-1986 you would only see the second feature. If you changed the end date for feature 3 to 12/31/1963 11:59pm, and the start date for feature 2 to 1/1/1964 12:00am, then you'd only see one at a time.